# I could not use a required font in Google Slides

Tags: google-slides, font

I was working on a project for a valued client. One of his requests was for me to use Myriad Pro font.
I wasn't able to meet that requirement with Google Slides, which was disappointing to the client and therefore to me.
Have I missed something, is there any way I could have done it?
Is there an enhancement in the pipeline for users to be able to load fonts of their own choice?
Seems like a bit of a deficiency in a good product.